# GridFS + express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx

I'm building an application that requires that a user be able upload audio files, and then at a later time request those same files. Being that I'm very new to all this, creating a file directory seems really confusing to me, GridFS ( storing the audio files in the database) seems to be easier to understand at this point.

What I am confused about is, if I go the direction of GridFS, does every user need to have a GridFS collection. Or would I somehow set up one main GridFS collection, and all user's audio files will be in that collection. Then in my mongoose user model I would save the names of the audio file's that belong to a given user. And then when the user requests their audio files, I will get the list of files that belong to that user, search the one main GridFS collection for those files?

I know that I might be better off setting up a file system(performance reasons), I looked into nginx, but I found myself just getting more and more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat gridFS as a collection with audio files (so we have fileId and content),
then you need to store fileId somewhere with owner record/document.

What can be an issue that storing pointer to user files in one document can go beyond max document size (16MB) - so if this could be a case - then we need a simple userId-fileId collection.
Have a fun!

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify the issue of going over the 16MB size document limit. If I understood what you are saying, It is possible that the user record/document which holds the pointers to all audio files that are owned by that user might become larger that 16MB, if the user has to many audio files ? In my case the user is limited to storing only 3 audio file, the size of the individual files can be larger than 16MB.

Comment: in this particular case just store reference to audio file in user document.